# how to use xlsx library to parse excel files within the browser

Tags: javascript, xlsx

I'm currently using xlsx library as a node module on the server, to parse Excel files.
From reading XLSX github page, it sounds like xlsx can also be used right within the actual browser to do this parsing without making any xhr calls to the server.

I could not find any examples of actually doing that.

There is an in-browser parsing demo here:  http://oss.sheetjs.com/

but I do not see any examples of how that actually done.

Could someone point me to the right direction, please?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was not looking well enough. I did fine the HTML5 parsing examples right on the github page. Now, that I'm trying that, I get this "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" error, but I will open a separate question for that.